# How to make specific maven dependency versions mandatory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, dependency-injection

I am working on creating a common library for my team which can be used by different micro-services of our team. Common library will be service-starter which includes : specific spring boot, spring version and other compatible versions and dependencies. Is it possible to guardrail using maven such that our whole team must be on specific **MUST versions** of some maven dependencies like spring boot version should be common across team (We will also have other maven dependencies which can be overridden in respective micro-service pom if needed.)

Comment: First is it neccessary to use a particular version? For example spring boot is brining new versions every 6 months.. No update possible? If so something is wrong? You must be able to upgrade... You could create a bom file which contains the suggested versions and release newer versions of your bom and communicate to the teams to upgrade them on a regular basis... And there is no real way to prevent people from using different versions of deps...

Comment: A library enforcing versions? Are you sure this is a library and not something else?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Planning to enforce a common spring boot version, some other common versions across the different services of the team. Is there any other better approach?

Comment: @martin552 Enforcing things should have a very good user story, because you are basically limiting your developers arbitrarily.   You are aware that Spring Boot has the BOM for this?  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html   Would that be enough for you or do you need more?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop your team from defining their own version in their project. However, you can add a `<dependencyManagement>`tag in your project which will define the versions you wish them to use so they won't have to decide.
But, again, nothing to stop them to override these.

Comment: Nothing in Maven.   The deployment procedure may explicitly control for these things and only allow those using whitelisted components.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parent pom that you want and put in `<dependencyManagement>` the dependencies that you want to be used by applications that use this parent pom.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>group-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

so if another application uses as parent pom the one you have declared above and uses as dependency

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>group-a</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

(It does not contain any specific version), it would retrieve by default the version which was delcared in parent pom of `1.0`

But the child pom application would always be free to declare their own version if they want, and use that instead, effectively overriding what was declared in parent pom

```
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>group-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

[More about Dependency management in Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: Additionally you could use the maven-enforcer-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) to disallow overriding of versions in the local poms. But primarily it should be made clear to the team, that they should use the versions defined in the parent.

Comment: Thanks @DrHopfen. Will be trying maven enforcer plugin.